# How can I select multiple cells in tableview with javafx only by mouse?

Tags: javafx, selection, cells

I have an application with a tableview in javafx and i want to select multiple cells only by mouse (something like the selection which exists in excel).I tried but i cant'n do something.

Comment: Have you tried something yet? For example any of the setOnMouseDrag() Eventhandler functions?

Comment: yes i tried but i can take only the cell from where the mousedragging started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer for this question is here  https://community.oracle.com/thread/2621389.